# Sublime Text SecTrustSettingsCopyCertificates: No Trust Settings were found

Tags: sublimetext3, package-control

Sometimes I run on this error when using sublime:

> Package Control
>
> Error executing: /usr/bin/security dump-trust-settings -d
>
> SecTrustSettingsCopyCertificates: No Trust Settings were found.
>
> VCS-based packages can be ignored with the "ignore_vcs_packages"
>   setting.

I've added `"ignore_vcs_packages": true,` to package control settings its still not working.

I'm using Yosemite and Sublime Text 3.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

See the issue here

https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/1002

in short- yes, this is due to trust issues.

Answer (score 1):

this is bug in **Package Control** which happen when you doesn't have any certificate file and cause Package Control to not update itself to fix this bug.

The quick fix is to had a dummy cert file with the `security` command:

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain ~/Downloads/localhost.cert
```

You can generate a dummy certificate with [this tool](http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/)

Then restart sublime and force update **Package Control** manually with `⌘ ^ P`

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.
Remove package control.
Manually install it.
remove package control from ignored_packages.
Thats it.

Comment: I got the following error message: `Package Control No list of preferred downloaders specified in the "downloader_precedence" setting for the platform "osx"` I had to restart ST3, it works now.